# Preventing Doctrine from Dropping / Recreating Database When using build --all

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

**The problem:**

- I have a database that's running on a shared server.
- I do not have permission to drop/ create a database via the command line

> > doctrine  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'opnsrce'@'173.236.128.0/255.255.128.0' to database 'dev'. Failing Query: "DROP DATABASE dev"
> >     doctrine  Creating "all" environment "doctrine" database
> >
> > doctrine  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'opnsrce'@'173.236.128.0/255.255.128.0' to database 'dev'. Failing Query: "CREATE DATABASE dev"

- This error occurs when I run
  `/dh/cgi-system/php5.cgi symfony
  doctrine:build --all
  --no-confirmation`

**The Question:** How do I run build-all while simultaneously telling doctrine to not drop / create the database (it already exists)?

**Update 1:**

What further information can I provide in order to help the SO community answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want all the classes to be rebuilt but the db not to be dropped and recreated, try running:

```
symfony doctrine:build --all-classes
```

The build task has a lot of different options and flags. Try running:

```
symfony help doctrine:build
```

to see all of your options.